# Dynamic add Buttons on search criteria in JavaFX

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx, textfield, changelistener

I'm trying to make a dynamic search in JavaFX. My search results are saved in Buttons which are on the left side of the page. The Buttons contain name as a text, and I want a dynamic search, so that if a name starts with "abc" for example there will only be Buttons shown that contain "abc". For example "abcdefg", "abcasdfj", but not "dfgas".

Right now I just added a Listener to a Textfield and removed and added Children which had these criterias.

see my code below:

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        for (int i = 0; i <= ListController.buttonList.size(); i++) {

            getChildren().remove(ListController.buttonList.get(i));

            if (ListController.buttonList.get(i).getText().equals(newValue)) {

                getChildren().add(ListController.buttonList.get(i));

            }

        }

    });
```

it works so far, but only if you type in the full name. Had the idea to use regex, but I'm sure there's a way that is not that complicated, isn't there?

Thanks in advance, really appreciate it!

Comment: just solved it by using     getText().contains(newValue); Still seems that this might be the wrong approach?

Comment: Take a look at [FilteredList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html).

Comment: And if you do that also take a look at [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)